# "Access can be packetLocal" - JAVA

Tags: java

La mayoría de los métodos que instancio en varias clases me piden que lo cambie a "packetLocal".
Ejemplo:

> public void ejemplo();

pasa a

> void ejemplo();

Entonces, ¿los métodos deberían ser públicos o no?

Comment: Obtengo el siguiente mensaje: "This inspection reports all fields, methods or classes, found in the specified inspection scope, that may have their access modifier narrowed down"

Comment: ¿Cual es el ámbito en el que quieres usar esos métodos?

Comment: Imagino que estás utilizando algún revisor de código como PMD o Checkstyle. De ser así, por favor agrega esta información en la pregunta.

Comment: Actualmente estoy usando IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso **seguramente el acceso a tu método se realiza únicamente dentro del paquete**, por esta razón la mejor práctica es usar el modificador de acceso default y **no es necesario agregar un modificador de acceso**. No debe ser public porque sería visible a todo mundo, se tendría acceso desde cualquier clase o instancia que en tu caso no es necesario.

**[Modificadores de acceso](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)**:

- `public` : visible a todo el mundo.
- `protected` : visible dentro del paquete y todas las subclases.
- `private` : visible únicamente a la clase que lo contiene.
- `default` : en el caso de este nivel de accesibilidad es visible dentro del paquete y no se requieren modificadores.

---

Aquí un buen articulo para más información:

[Modificadores de acceso public, protected, default y private en Java.](https://www.programarya.com/Cursos/Java/Modificadores-De-Acceso)

Answer (score 0):

Esto depende en que forma estes usando los métodos si lo dejas
con `public` otras clases tendrán acceso al método, si le quitas el `public`  pasará a ser `private` y solo tendras acceso al método desde tu misma clase.

Comment: *"si le quitas el `public` pasará a ser `private`"* esto puede pasar en otros LPs, pero no en Java. Para que un método sea privado en Java, necesitas marcarlo como `private`. Cuando no tiene definición de la visibilidad, Java le asigna visibilidad por defecto, lo cual permite a cualquier elemento (clase, interfaz, enum, etc) **del mismo paquete** acceder a este elemento.